# Polymer 1.X + jQuery $(window).scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using Polymer + jQuery in a project.
How can i use the jQuery $(window).scroll function ?
I have tried this code and it doesn't output anything in my console.

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("polymer"); // output=polymer
    $(document).scroll(function(){
    console.log('scrolling'); // no output
    if($(this).scrollTop() == 0){
          console.log('scroll top = 0'); //no output
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

This problem is about using Polymer alongside jQuery ?. I have to mention that jQuery selectors are working (eg. `$("#element")` ) .

If yes, how can i get the scrollTop() value (or trigger when it's 0) and when is 0 i have to add a padding to an element.

Comment: i have tried the above code in your example with polymer and its working ! do you have any online example or more information e.g jQuery version, browser, polymer etc ...

Comment: Yes this is the jquery script : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" async></script>`

Comment: hi i have tested this code again with the jQuery version you mentioned and  it's working, i think you have to share a live demo of what you are doing, so we can help you :)

Comment: need more info about the polymer setup to debug this. what elements are being used and so forth.

Comment: You probably have a (#mainContainer) div so that's why window is not working. So try ($("#mainContainer").scroll .... )